# Column search on top of table with responsive table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have prepared table with server side script for column search, everything works fine, but stuck with one issue for responsive table,
Below is my table,

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" id="3table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Number1</th>
            <th> Number2</th>
            <th>Plant</th>
            <th>Part</th>    
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Date3</th>
            <th>Transport</th>
            <th>Docket</th>        
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="1"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="2"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="3"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="4"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="5"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="6"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="7"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="8"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="9"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="10"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-column="11"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>            
            <td><input type="text" data-column="12"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I had kept another  with  for search box, then sending search value with below jquery code

```
// Apply the search

$('.form-control').on( 'keyup click', function () {   // for text boxes
    var i =$(this).attr('data-column');  // getting column index
    var v =$(this).val();  // getting search input value
    var table = $('#3table').DataTable();
    table.columns(i).search(v).draw();
});
```

Now when i change resolution, search boxes are not changed resolution as other columns and rows, All search boxes are not wrapping, but showing in 1 row only. if i remove 2nd , then my datatable is completely responsive,means i can see + sign for first column for columns which are getting hidden.

How can i make search boxes responsive as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

You have two `thead` elements, there should be only one.

> **SOLUTION**

Combine two header rows under one `thead` element.

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" id="3table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Number1</th>
            <th> Number2</th>
            <th>Plant</th>
            <th>Part</th>    
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Date3</th>
            <th>Transport</th>
            <th>Docket</th>        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="1"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="2"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="3"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="4"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="5"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="6"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="7"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="8"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="9"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="10"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
            <th><input type="text" data-column="11"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>            
            <th><input type="text" data-column="12"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

> **NOTES**

There are other issues with your code:

- ID should not start from a number, consider giving your table another ID
- Your code for search boxes should be changed to:

  ```js
  // Prevent sorting when search boxes are clicked
  $('#3table thead').on( 'click', '.form-control', function (e) {   // for text boxes
     e.stopPropagation();
  });

  // Perform column search
  $('#3table thead').on( 'keyup change', '.form-control', function (e) {          
     var i = $(this).attr('data-column');  // getting column index
     var v = $(this).val();  // getting search input value
     var table = $('#3table').DataTable();
     table.columns(i).search(v).draw();
  });
  ```
- Use `orderCellsTop: true` option to use top header row for sorting.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1p18e0uL/1/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive columns with

```
className="none"
```

from Gyrocode.com 
UPDATED DEMO :  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dadmand/7yhtu2um/)